# Send messages to multiple users

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've a model `UserPhoneNumber`. I want to send message to `multiple phone numbers`.
I've applied `ForeignKey` to `to_number` not `M2M` because I want to keep track of each phone number. like, Does this message is `delivered or not`.

How do I send messages to multiple users? Should I use inline-formset? or any other idea? or bulk create

```
class UserCellPhone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

class SentMessage(models.Model):
    to_number = models.ForeignKey(UserCellPhone)

    account_sid = models.CharField(max_length=34, default="", blank=True)

    body = models.TextField(max_length=160, default="", blank=True)

    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    delivered_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, it seems that you misunderstand how M2M work.

In your case, it seems that a message can ben sent to **many** numbers. And a number can receive **many** messages -> You DO need a **Many**2**Many** relation. There is no other solution.

In a "conceptual way" (in Django), when you design a M2M relation, you define 2 models (`UserCellPhone` and `SentMessage`) but in reality (ie. what's happening at the database level), there will be 3 tables involved because Django will create a table to link your both models with a M2M relation.

If you want to specify the third table used with Django, you can do it this way, using your example:

```
class UserCellPhone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class SentMessage(models.Model):
    to_number = models. ManyToManyField(UserCellPhone, through='MessagesDelivery')
```

This way, Django will create 3 tables, and the MessagesDelivery table will contain couples with a FK to UserCellPhone + a FK to SentMessage.

For example, if message_38 is sent to usercellphone_45 and usercellphone_67, your MessagesDelivery table will look like:

```
-- sent_message_id - usercellphone_id 
-- 38 - 45
-- 38 - 67
```

This is how a M2M relation work (not only in Django).